# Are there any languages which incorporate integer maths into their type system?

Tags: generics, types, language-design

I've been thinking a little bit about a hypothetical language feature, and I'm wondering if any languages have done anything similar that I could learn from, or that could provide relevant search terms.

It's pretty common for languages to allow types to be specialised with constrained type parameters, often referred to as generics. For example, `Foo<Bar>` as a type.

I'm curious whether any languages allow us to parameterise types with specific integer values, like `Foo<10>`. A simple example of a use case might be a fixed length array that could be statically checked by the type checker.

I'm particularly interested in languages that might allow basic mathematical operations within the type system. This C# style pseudocode would concatenate two fixed length arrays into a third fixed length array with a known length, which would be calculated and treated as a constant by the compiler.

```
FixedArray<Length1 + Length2> Concat<Length1, Length2>(FixedArray<Length1> a, FixedArray<Length2> b)
    where Length1: Integer, >= 0
    where Length2: Integer, >= 0
    {}
```

I'm aware of TypeScript, which comes close. It allows constants as types, so `Foo<10>` is valid. However, I believe the type system treats them more like enums or symbols, and doesn't understand them as mathematical values. There are ways to fake this a bit using overloading.

Research keywords and documents discussing features like this - even if not implemented in a language - are of interest. Resources that don't presume a deep familiarity with type theory are preferred, although I'll take anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ you can parametrize templates with integers. In fact there is a `template struct array<class T, size_t N>` in the standard. You can define a function to concatenate it with compile time type check as follows:

```
template<class T, size_t N1, size_t N2> array<T, N1+N2> concat(
    const array<T, N1> &a, const array<T, N2> &b)
{
    array<T, N1+N2> ret;
    /* copy data into ret */
    return ret;
}
```

When used, the types will be checked during compilation:

```
array<T, 10> a;
array<T, 5> b;
array<T, 14> ab1 = concat(a, b); // error
array<T, 15> ab2 = concat(a, b); // works
auto ab3 = concat(a, b); // type of ab3 is auto-deduced to array<T, 15>
```

Here's a [working example](https://ideone.com/wDF0xb).

Comment: Oh dear, I should have remembered that! It's been a long time since I've used C++. C++ calls these "non-type template parameters" which is pretty unhelpful for looking up other similar things. You wouldn't happen to know of another name for this type of compile type mathematical expression capability, would you? I'll probably accept this answer either way, thanks, and Doh! to me for forgetting that.

Comment: @Sam: I don't know of a specific name for this. For me it's just another form of compile-time evaluation.

Answer (score 2):

I think the term you might be looking for is [dependently typed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type). It's not a terribly specific term, but it means that the types can depend on values, which generally includes numbers.

Here is an example for [Idris](https://www.idris-lang.org/), a dependently typed programming language:

```
total
append : Vect n a -> Vect m a -> Vect (n + m) a
append Nil       ys = ys
append (x :: xs) ys = x :: append xs ys
```

The `n` and `m` are type parameters of `Vect` represent the length of the vectors, so the length of the result of appending two `Vect`s together is `n + m`.